# Delete a row or consecutive rows (from 1 to 5) in which there is 0 as a value of one of the two columns (or both)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
A    B
1    2
0    0
0    0
0    1
2    0
3    1
```

I have to change it based on the following conditions:

-Delete a row or consecutive rows (from 1 to 5) in which there is a 0 on either the A or the B (or both) columns

-Delete consecutive rows (more than 20) in which there is a 0 on either the A or the B columns

I'm expecting this as an output:

```
A    B
1    2
3    1
```

Comment: Hi! Would you mind elaborating a bit more on the conditions? I understand that you want to filter on the appearances of `0`'s but I don't understand what happens to consecutive rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to count the successive zeros:

```
# is any value 0?
m = df.eq(0).any(axis=1)

# is the row part of a stretch of
# up to N consecutive 0?
m2 = df.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size').le(5)

# keep only rows that don't match the two conditions
out = df[~(m&m2)]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
5  3  1
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,0,0,0,2,3],
                   'B': [2,0,0,1,0,1]})
```